# erase windows and keep ubuntu to dual boot with parrot security

Tags: boot

I was wondering if there was any way that I could completely wipe windows from my p.c. while keeping Ubuntu and then dual boot another linux distro like parrot security....or is this too good to be true?

I'm using Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

This is completely fine. Grub will still exist after the deletion of the Windows partition. Dual booting parrot with Ubuntu will work fine as well. The one scenario you'd want to be cautious about is dual booting windows with Linux already present on you drive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your caution message.  Do you mean if I already had Linux installed and wanted to install windows, that I'd need to be cautious of the install since Linux is already installed?

Comment: @new2ubuntu Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks a bunch!  Any idea how I'd wipe windows off without actually logging into windows?  Any way to do it from Ubuntu 19.04 that I'm using dual booted now? Or would I need to log into windows to wipe windows?

Comment: @new2ubuntu You can use gparted to delete the Windows partition. If you don't have gparted, install it with `sudo apt install gparted`. Make sure you only delete the Windows partition, otherwise bad things can happen... Then, to remove the Windows option from grub, run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Ok thanks!  I'd be sure to know the Windows partition because it would be the one named /dev/sda?